# How many bits are actually used on the Status Register (8086)

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, x86-16, status-register

Asked this in class, I think I understand it but not sure so I wanted to confirm.

The Status Register has 16 bits, with each bit having a flag. However, the image provided in our lecture slides shows otherwise?

[image: Status register]

The image shows that only certain bits actually have flags. Does this mean that only those bits are actually being used? That the rest of the bits are just fodder?

I'm sorry if my question is unclear, I can attempt to explain more if anyone asks.

**Currently**, I'm thinking that only 9 bits are actually being used?

Comment: The diagram is incorrect. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) for all bits.

Comment: And note that the FLAGS register has been expanded to the 32 bit EFLAGS register and then to the 64 bit RFLAGS register with some bits beyond the first 16 having a meaning.

Comment: @FUZxxl, he "clearly" says in the question (title) that he's talking about the 8086 and not the more advance pentiums, celeron, xeon processors.

Comment: Manveer, it would be good if you would make the image inline (put it in your post) so when removed from imgur.com, stackoverflow still has it.

Comment: @AlexisWilke I would love to, but this is my first post so I don't have enough rep to do inline images yet ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, it is shown as a «16 bit register» because it is a logical size for a register.

In the actual implementation (the way the processor was created) it is often that they will only have the 9 bits. The other "bits" are lines directly connected to the Ground pin (or +1.2V or whatever the voltage would have been there.) This is because memory is expensive and if you can save a few bits, the hardware is cheaper (think about saving 5 bits x 10 million processors...)

In newer implementation, I would imagine they do not bother as much, although computers do things like that automatically, so there would again be no reason to have a real bit of memory if it is to keep it to 0 all the time.

So as a programmer, as far as you are concerned, it is 16 bits. For a hardware engineer, it is likely *just* 9 bits. You just have to make sure that you can still push the flags on the stack properly (that the other 5 bits will always be a known value, in most cases that will be zero).

---

Further Details:

To access the flag register, as a programmer, you use `PUSHF` and `POPF`.

```
; read to AX
PUSHF
POP AX

; write from AX
PUSH AX
POPF
```

*(As a side note in regard to FUZxxl comments above, the old PUSHF and POPF instructions are 16 bits, the newer versions are 32 or 64 bits. This is important to keep the stack properly aligned.)*

As mentioned by Ped7g, although you can put any random value in AX and do a `PUSH` + `POPF`, it is not good practice. Usually, when you want to change a flag for which there is no instruction, you do:

```
PUSHF
POP AX
OR 10h       ; set flag A to 1
PUSH AX
POPF
```

The other ways to change a flag is by using certain instructions. This is defined in the instruction directly. There are a few instructions such as `CLD` and `STC` which directly clear or set of flag. And there are others such as `SBB` that will tweak the borrow and `ADC` that tweak the carry (and N, Z, V flags...)

Finally, there are ways to check the basic flags with branch instructions. In many cases, this is used with the `CMP` instruction (on newer processor, there are MANY reasons why a flag might change...) This allows you to compare a register against another value and branch if it is smaller, larger, equal, smaller or equal, larger or equal, generates an overflow. So an instruction such as `JC` reads the C flag and jumps if true (set to 1).

In older processors, most of the flags where in link with branches. The 8086 added the A flag for "Arithmetic" operations (doing additions and subtractions in decimal) and the D flag for "Direction" (see `LOOPCX`, `MOVB`).

Later it added many other flags for so many things that I won't list them here. Some of these were useful to know whether a certain instruction existed, and since then we have a `CPUID` instruction for extensions, everything you need to know about the CPU and it can even be patched at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assume that since this is for Computer Architecture class, my prof is expecting 9 bits as the answer.

Just as a followup, you say that for the programmer that it is 16 bits essentially. I do not understand the status register that well, does this mean that the programmer can access all 16 bits for programming?

Comment: @ManveerBhullar: I think a try to modify reserved bits is technically undefined behaviour. You can for sure read all the bits, just PUSHF (flags on the stack), and pop it back into regular register like `ax`. But modification by POPF may not work on some CPUs, or have unexpected results on unexpected CPUs (where "reserved" bit in future starts to have some effect). So for reading all 16b are accessible.

Comment: STD sets the DF (direction flag) to 1 (backwards), I'm unsure about what SEC is. CLD Would clear the DF flag (forward). STC would set the CF carry flag, CLC would clear it.

Comment: I fixed `SEC` (from 6502) with `STC`.